# Journey Builder Schedule Contact Evaluation

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have an Automation to Import Data in Marketing Cloud based on File drop in FTP. Then I am using this Automation as a Schedule to run the Journey when it completes. Now in Contact Evaluation, by default it is set to "Evaluate all records" but I want to Evaluate only new records added in the data extension. Please advise. TIA

Comment: Is your import an add/update or an overwrite?

Comment: @EazyE It's Add and update. I tried with only Add as well but same thing.